# Cache objects don't expire ASP Net C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, caching, webforms

I am working on a caching feature for my web forms application.  I want to keep track of the number of times a user entered in a username (same or different) for purposes of blocking that IP.

I use an absolute expiration of 1 minute so that the cache object expires after 1 minute from creation regardless of last access.

However, when I run the application (using visual studio development server), the cache does not expire unless I rebuild the project.

I searched online and found a few solutions, such as setting the sliding expiration to  `NoSlidingExpiration`, and also using a custom counter class to store the data.

I also found a solution which uses the web.config cache element inside the `system.web` tags:

```
<caching>
  <cache disableExpiration="false"/>
</caching>
```

The cache still does not expire. Any help would be great. Here is the code I am using.

```
private int CacheCheck()
{
    // Create the keys used and retrive the values from the cahce
    IncrementingCacheObject cacheUsername = Cache[KeyUsername] as IncrementingCacheObject;
    IncrementingCacheObject cacheDiffAttempts = Cache[KeyDiffAttempts] as IncrementingCacheObject;
    IncrementingCacheObject cacheSameAttempts = Cache[KeySameAttempts] as IncrementingCacheObject;

    // Check if the username exists in cache
    if (cacheUsername != null)
    {
        if (cacheUsername.Username.Equals(this.txtUserName.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            if (cacheSameAttempts != null)
            {
                cacheSameAttempts.Count++;
                this.Cache[KeySameAttempts] = cacheSameAttempts;
            }
            else
            {
                cacheSameAttempts = new IncrementingCacheObject { Count = 0, ExpireDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1), Username = this.txtUserName.Text };
                Cache.Insert(KeySameAttempts, cacheSameAttempts, null, cacheSameAttempts.ExpireDate, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (cacheDiffAttempts != null)
            {
                cacheDiffAttempts.Count++;
                this.Cache[KeyDiffAttempts] = cacheDiffAttempts;
            }
            else
            {
                cacheDiffAttempts = new IncrementingCacheObject { Count = 0, ExpireDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1), Username = this.txtUserName.Text };
                Cache.Insert(KeyDiffAttempts, cacheDiffAttempts, null, cacheDiffAttempts.ExpireDate, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
            }
        }

        // Set the last used username value in the Cache to the value in the text box
        cacheUsername.Username = this.txtUserName.Text;
        this.Cache[KeyUsername] = cacheUsername;
    }
    else
    {
        cacheUsername = new IncrementingCacheObject { Count = 0, ExpireDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1), Username = this.txtUserName.Text };
        cacheDiffAttempts = new IncrementingCacheObject { Count = 0, ExpireDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1), Username = this.txtUserName.Text };
        cacheSameAttempts = new IncrementingCacheObject { Count = 0, ExpireDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1), Username = this.txtUserName.Text };
        Cache.Insert(KeyUsername, cacheUsername, null, cacheUsername.ExpireDate, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
        Cache.Insert(KeySameAttempts, cacheSameAttempts, null, cacheSameAttempts.ExpireDate, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
        Cache.Insert(KeyDiffAttempts, cacheDiffAttempts, null, cacheDiffAttempts.ExpireDate, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration);
    }

    cacheUsername = Cache[KeyUsername] as IncrementingCacheObject;
    cacheDiffAttempts = Cache[KeyDiffAttempts] as IncrementingCacheObject;
    cacheSameAttempts = Cache[KeySameAttempts] as IncrementingCacheObject;
    // Check whether any log in attempts have surpassed the threshold and return a value to indicate what kind of log in was detected
    if (cacheDiffAttempts != null && cacheDiffAttempts.Count >= MaxLogAttemptsBeforeBan)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (cacheSameAttempts != null && cacheSameAttempts.Count >= MaxLogAttemptsBeforeBan)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return -1;
}

    /// <summary>
    /// This will reset the cache to blank/starting values.
    /// </summary>
    private void ResetCache()
    {
        Cache.Remove(KeyUsername);
        Cache.Remove(KeySameAttempts);
        Cache.Remove(KeyDiffAttempts);
    }

    // Class used to store objects in the cache
    private class IncrementingCacheObject
    {
        public string Username;
        public int Count;
        public DateTime ExpireDate;
    }
```

When the user logs in successfully, before the page is redirected, it calls the ResetCache() method.

Comment: Have you looked at max login attempts using a membership provider? http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership.maxinvalidpasswordattempts.aspx

Comment: @PaulZahra - No I have not, the application is not using a membership provider unfortunately.

Comment: Are you setting the absolute expiration property of the cache policy?

Comment: Generally you have little to no control over when the cache is wiped, you can alter the 'priority' and mark it as important, but that's about it - it can be cleared at any time by the OS... see http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/290935/Using-MemoryCache-in-Net for a nice implementation.

Comment: For such short lived data - how many login attempts until they login, caching seems a bit overkill... why not store it in the session or log it in a DB along with their IP?

Comment: @PaulZahra -  I want to avoid the session or cookies. I also want to limit the access to the database. This cache feature is meant to be a first line of defense against malicious attackers on the web site. The Cache is meant to prevent slow downs of the network in cases like DOS attacks.

Comment: Limiting database interaction is perhaps an arguably valid reason... but would provide much more long term security... what if your cache expires half way through a users multiple login attempts... what if you limit attempts to 5 and they do 4 every day for 6 months until they are in?

Comment: @PaulZahra - Good point. The main use is to block attackers trying to log in multiple times in a short amount of time. There are cases that can be ignored here since the actual verification of the user will handle the rest. But if a user tries to log in multiple times before hitting the limit and stops, then it probably won't be a big concern, at least for now.

Comment: Why are you setting the absolute expiry as cacheSameAttempts.ExpireDate... what exactly is cacheSameAttempts.ExpireDate ?

Comment: @PaulZahra -  I am using a solution I found here `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902255/asp-net-cache-absolute-expiration-not-working`. They created a cache counter object with an expiration date time. They used the objects expiration date time value for the absolute expiration for the cache.

Comment: How are `Key...` strings defined?

Comment: They are class constants like this `private const string KeyUsername = "LastAttemptedUsername";`

Comment: @RXC I would recommend using CacheItemPriority and set it as high as possible, bearing in mind your system constraints to attempt to minimise the cache being wiped.

Comment: @RXC Also why aren't you using HttpContext.Current.Cache as they do in the solution you are using? This could well obfuscate your current cache not expiring issue.

Comment: You might not see the cached item expire until it is next accessed. This probably depends on CacheItemPriority.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out the issue I was having.

I found this solution online:

[Stackoverflow Questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5902255/asp-net-cache-absolute-expiration-not-working)

I needed to change some code around to work. I had to remove any direct assignments to the Cache and use the insert method. Here is the new code. Also, changed to use `HttpContect.Current.Cache`

```
private int CacheCheck()
{
    // Create the keys used and retrive the values from the cahce
    IncrementingCacheObject cacheUsername = Cache[KeyUsername] as IncrementingCacheObject;
    IncrementingCacheObject cacheDiffAttempts = Cache[KeyDiffAttempts] as IncrementingCacheObject;
    IncrementingCacheObject cacheSameAttempts = Cache[KeySameAttempts] as IncrementingCacheObject;

    // Check if the username exists in cache
    if (cacheUsername != null)
    {
        if (cacheUsername.Username.Equals(this.txtUserName.Text, StringComparison.InvariantCultureIgnoreCase))
        {
            if (cacheSameAttempts != null)
            {
                cacheSameAttempts.Count++;
            }
            else
            {
                cacheSameAttempts = new IncrementingCacheObject { Count = 0, ExpireDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1), Username = this.txtUserName.Text };
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(KeySameAttempts, cacheSameAttempts, null, cacheSameAttempts.ExpireDate, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Default, null);
        }
        else
        {
            if (cacheDiffAttempts != null)
            {
                cacheDiffAttempts.Count++;
            }
            else
            {
                cacheDiffAttempts = new IncrementingCacheObject { Count = 0, ExpireDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1), Username = this.txtUserName.Text };
            }

            HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(KeyDiffAttempts, cacheDiffAttempts, null, cacheDiffAttempts.ExpireDate, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Default, null);
        }

        // Set the last used username value in the Cache to the value in the text box
        cacheUsername.Username = this.txtUserName.Text;
    }
    else
    {
        cacheUsername = new IncrementingCacheObject { Count = 0, ExpireDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1), Username = this.txtUserName.Text };
        cacheDiffAttempts = new IncrementingCacheObject { Count = 0, ExpireDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1), Username = this.txtUserName.Text };
        cacheSameAttempts = new IncrementingCacheObject { Count = 0, ExpireDate = DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(1), Username = this.txtUserName.Text };
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(KeySameAttempts, cacheSameAttempts, null, cacheSameAttempts.ExpireDate, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Default, null);
        HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(KeyDiffAttempts, cacheDiffAttempts, null, cacheDiffAttempts.ExpireDate, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Default, null);
    }

    HttpContext.Current.Cache.Insert(KeyUsername, cacheUsername, null, cacheUsername.ExpireDate, System.Web.Caching.Cache.NoSlidingExpiration, CacheItemPriority.Default, null);

    // Check whether any log in attempts have surpassed the threshold and return a value to indicate what kind of log in was detected
    if (cacheDiffAttempts != null && cacheDiffAttempts.Count >= MaxLogAttemptsBeforeBan)
    {
        return 0;
    }

    if (cacheSameAttempts != null && cacheSameAttempts.Count >= MaxLogAttemptsBeforeBan)
    {
        return 1;
    }

    return -1;
}

/// <summary>
/// This will reset the cache to blank/starting values.
/// </summary>
private void ResetCache()
{
    HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove(KeyUsername);
    HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove(KeySameAttempts);
    HttpContext.Current.Cache.Remove(KeyDiffAttempts);
}

// Class used to store objects in the cache
private class IncrementingCacheObject
{
    public string Username;
    public int Count;
    public DateTime ExpireDate;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do not use `DateTime.UtcNow`, `Cache` expects absolute expiration expressed as local time. Use `DateTime.Now.AddMinutes`.

Comment: I originally used `DateTime.Now` and it did not work either, but I can retry with all changes I made. I will update if it works.

Comment: @RXC Try using DateTimeOffset

Comment: @Igor I'm afraid you are wrong it seems... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4y13wyk9%28v=vs.110%29.aspx "The time at which the inserted object expires and is removed from the cache. To avoid possible issues with local time such as changes from standard time to daylight saving time, use UtcNow rather than Now for this parameter value. If you are using absolute expiration, the slidingExpiration parameter must be NoSlidingExpiration." P.S. I don't down vote ;)

Comment: @PaulZahra - you are right, they must go by DateTime.Kind to differentiate between UTC and local times. In the code example they still use `DateTime.Now`.